# Crontab expression in Spring

Tags: cron

I am trying to make a scheduled task where cron job executes after every 15 minutes, but I am confused about seconds.

I have made the following cron: ("* 0/15 * * * *") . Is it same as
("0 0/15 * * * *") [Note the second part here]. I mean in online I have seen examples where seconds is replaced by 0, but other fields with *. So my question is, if I replace seconds field with *, then is it same as with 0 ?

Comment: https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Sorry if I do not sound smart, but it does not have seconds field at all, but Spring scheduled cron annotation has

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--

Comment: Okay, thank you. Should have read the documentation before posting this question. Sorry for wasting your time people, but thank you for your input nevertheless.